Why is my Scala project failing to find java.sql.Driver?
I have written a Scala+AKKA api using Scala 3. I then wanted to use Hibernate ORM to store data on the backend. I followed this guide: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.6/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#introduction to get a basic example to being expanding from. I substituted the H2 implementation in the guide for MySQL due to memory requirements.
When I try to initiate the database, I get the following exception:
[error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[error]     at ServerRoutes.$init$$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(ServerRoutes.scala:34)
[error]     at akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.ApplyConverterInstances.akka$http$scaladsl$server$util$ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$1$$_$apply$$anonfun$1(ApplyConverterInstances.scala:14)
[error]     at akka.http.scaladsl.server.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$3.apply$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$1(Directive.scala:234)

...

[error] Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get java.sql.Driver from DriverManager

...

[error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get java.sql.Driver from DriverManager
[error]     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.newDriver(ConnectionFactory.java:130)
[error]     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.<init>(ConnectionFactory.java:68)
[error]     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:112)
[error]     at io.agroal.pool.DataSource.<init>(DataSource.java:37)
[error]     at io.agroal.pool.DataSourceProvider.getDataSource(DataSourceProvider.java:21)
[error]     at io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource.from(AgroalDataSource.java:41)
[info]  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:136)
[info]  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:247)
[info]  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
[info]  at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry.requireService(ServiceRegistry.java:68)
[info]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:434)
[error]     at io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource.from(AgroalDataSource.java:33)
[error]     at org.hibernate.agroal.internal.AgroalConnectionProvider.configure(AgroalConnectionProvider.java:93)
[error]     ... 78 more
[error] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
[error]     at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:300)
[error]     at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.newDriver(ConnectionFactory.java:128)
[error]     ... 85 more
[info]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:305)
[info]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:129)
[info]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:81)
[info]  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
[info]  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)

I've looked around at why this could be happening and i've seen several reports about the driver not being on the classpath. However, from what I can tell, it absolutely should be.
build.sbt dependencies:
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka"       %% "akka-http"                % akkaHttpVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"                   %% "akka-http-spray-json"     % akkaHttpVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"                   %% "akka-actor-typed"         % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka"                   %% "akka-stream"              % akkaVersion,
    "ch.qos.logback"                      % "logback-classic"           % "1.5.12",
    "com.thesamet.scalapb"                %% "scalapb-runtime"          % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf",
    "com.thesamet.scalapb"                %% "scalapb-json4s"           % "0.12.1",
    "commons-codec"                       % "commons-codec"             % "1.17.1",
    "com.typesafe.akka"                   %% "akka-http-testkit"        % akkaHttpVersion                                         % Test,
    "com.typesafe.akka"                   %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion                                             % Test,
    "org.scalatest"                       %% "scalatest"                % "3.2.19"                                                % Test,
    "org.hibernate.orm"                   % "hibernate-core"            % "6.6.3.Final",
    "org.hibernate.validator"             % "hibernate-validator"       % "8.0.0.Final",
    "org.glassfish"                       % "jakarta.el"                % "5.0.0-M1"                                              % Test,
    "io.agroal"                           % "agroal-pool"               % "2.5",
    "org.hibernate.orm"                   % "hibernate-agroal"          % "6.4.4.Final",
    "com.mysql"                           % "mysql-connector-j"         % "9.1.0",
    "com.lihaoyi"                         %% "upickle"                  % "4.0.2"
  )

And finally, the section of code creating the database:
def init() : Unit = {
  sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(classOf[Registration])
    .setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
    .setProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hydra_data")
    .setProperty("user", "root")
    .setProperty("password", "")
    // use Agroal connection pool
    .setProperty("hibernate.agroal.maxSize", "20")
    // display SQL in console
    .setProperty("show_sql", "true")
    .setProperty("format_sql", "true")
    .setProperty("highlight_sql", "true")
    .buildSessionFactory()
 sessionFactory.getSchemaManager.exportMappedObjects(true)
...

}

Any suggestions? I presume (please correct me if i'm wrong) that as I have the mysql-connector-j dependency, that the Driver should be on the classpath. So I'm really unsure what the problem is here? This happens when I run 'sbt run' or run through the IDE
Java Version:OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)
Scala version: 3.6.2
Sbt version: 1.10.6
UPDATE:
As suggested by @GaëlJ I tried the following:
val sqlDriver = classOf[com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver]
This works fine. I also found this post: How to use MySQL JDBC driver in an SBT Scala project?
and tried adding this to my database init function
classOf[com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver].getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()

but I get the same error that the DriverManager could not load the driver.
UPDATE 2:
I followed some of the links to the internal Hibernate files in the error output. I found that the ConnectionFactory class calls DriverManager.getDriver and passes the URL defined in the config to the function to determine which Driver to use.
So I did this manually and I get the correct response. So why is this failing internally? Is this a bug perhaps?

UPDATE 3:
Have submitted a potential bug report: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-18934
UPDATE 4:
I decided today to debug through the Hibernate initialisation code to see what exactly was going wrong.
I tracked the issue into the ConnectioFactory constructor. When it tries to request the driver, it accesses configuration.jdbcUrl(), which is null. So it runs DriverManager.getDriver(null), which throws the error when I ran DriverManager.getDriver(null) manually:

Which trickles up the Hibernate exception handling and comes out with the original error (it is actually the bottom exception of the entire original error).
I have updated the bug report. It seems the connection URL is not correctly being placed into the Agroal configuration when it creates the service and tries to instantiate it.

JDK 23 is compatible with scala since 3.3.5 and you are using scala 3.3.4. The link to hibernate doc is for 6.3 but you set hibernate 6.6 in your build.sbt. Based on the hibernate docs, you don't need to set dialect and driver classpath unless you use a custom Dialect.

I'm wondering why you want to use hibernate in a scala project. Hibernate works with scala I think, but it's designed for Java. There are other libraries that are better match with scala

@GastónSchabas I hadn't noticed the differences in version numbers, though the documentation between Hibernate 6.3 and 6.6 are virtually identical.
I have chosen Hibernate because I have familiarity with it in some of my other Java projects and thought it would be simple to implement (which is mostly true except for this issue)

@GastónSchabas also I am not specifying classpath or language dialect explicitly, yet I am having this issue.
Also with your previous comment, scala 3.3.5 does not exist. Did you mean 3.4.0? Either way I have updated to 3.6.2 to ensure its not out of date.

You can do something like classOf[...MySQLDriver] to check if it really is available at runtime, maybe you have something else that removes it. Otherwise, it could be a config issue with Hibernate, you could set breakpoints to double check what Hibernate is trying to load.

If you're not able to load the driver manually, this doesn't sound like a bug with Hibernate nor your config. What exact error do you get when you call newInstance?

@GaëlJ no error except the original exception. I am also able to manually call DriverManager.getDriver(connectionURL) which successfully returns the correct driver. This is the exact line of code that when executed by Hibernate in the ConnectionFactory class, throws an exception. This is what lead me to believe it is a bug (see UPDATE 2 in the question)

@GaëlJ please see my latest update. I'm now almost certain this is a bug in Hibernate/Agroal with it not correctly passing the jdbcUrl when requesting the driver from DriverManager

I think I have found the issue. The problem was with my configuration and the Hibernate starter guide. This might save some other people some time.
The starter guide has references to URL, USER variables when setting the config, which from the imports, suggests these are available from:
org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.*
Which might be true for Java. However, they are actually located in an inherited class:
org.hibernate.cfg.JdbcSettings
So in Scala:
import org.hibernate.cfg.JdbcSettings._
This then allowed me to set my config like this:
val config = new Configuration()
  .addAnnotatedClass(classOf[Registration])
  .setProperty(JAKARTA_JDBC_URL, getConnectionString)
  .setProperty(JAKARTA_JDBC_USER, user)
  .setProperty(JAKARTA_JDBC_PASSWORD, pw)
  // use Agroal connection pool
  .setProperty("hibernate.agroal.maxSize", "20")
  // display SQL in console
  .setProperty(SHOW_SQL, "true")
  .setProperty(FORMAT_SQL, "true")
  .setProperty(HIGHLIGHT_SQL, "true")

Another note, the documentation is actually out of date. URL, USER and PASS are deprecated, you must use JAKARTA_JDBC_* (see above config) to set the values.
This fixed the above issue, so I'm marking this as resolved. I am now getting issues connecting to the database, which is outside the scope of the original question. I hope (given I found several people online having the same problems), this saves someone some time.
